# UNION two queries with aliases, WHERE condition by alias

Tags: mysql, sql

Take the bellow query:

```
/*select customers with data*/
SELECT tbl2.id,tbl2.customer,count from tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.id
WHERE tbl2.customer = @customer /*parameter*/

UNION

/*select all customers*/
select id,costumer,NULL as 'count' from tbl1
```

The above query would output:

```
id  customer count
2   john     34
45  Anna      8
2   john     12
8   Pepe     22
2   john     NULL
45  Anna     NULL
8   Pepe     NULL
43  Mark     NULL
1   Alice    NULL
```

The desired output would be:

```
id  customer count
2   john     34
45  Anna      8
2   john     12
8   Pepe     22
43  Mark     NULL
1   Alice    NULL
```

So, the second query should pull only the rows with different `id`'s from the first query, using `UNION`, and not a `LEFT JOIN`!

Pseudo example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT tbl2.id,tbl2.customer,count from tbl1
  JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.id
) a

UNION

SELECT * FROM (
  select id,costumer,NULL as 'count' from tbl1  
) b

WHERE a.id != b.id
```

I know I can use LEFT JOIN. Is the above possible?

Comment: Why not use `LEFT JOIN`?  That is the right way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `NOT EXISTS`?

```
SELECT tbl2.id, tbl2.customer, count
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl2.id = tbl1.id

UNION ALL

SELECT id, costumer, NULL AS 'count'
FROM tbl1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tbl2
        WHERE tbl2.id = tbl1.id
        );
```

Even tho I don't see a reason not to use `LEFT JOIN`, that's the purpose of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl1.id,
        tbl1.customer,
        (select count from tbl2 where tbl2.id = tbl1.id) as count
from tbl1
```

Edited:

This code brings ID and CUSTOMER , which by the way you have in both tables , and in the third column made ​​a subselect to get data from the table two, remembering that subselects can be time consuming and delay the query.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Ajean, edited the answer, beter now ? any sugestion be free to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT tbl2.id,tbl2.customer,count from tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.id
WHERE tbl2.customer = @customer) AS table_1 /*parameter*/

UNION

/*select all customers*/
select id,costumer,NULL as 'count' from table_1
```